# I have issue with numpad jquery. I want the user input to display on where the user clicks the numpad

Tags: html, jquery

What I want to achieve is after user clicks on any block the numpad pops up, and displays user input in the class 'amount' where the user clicks the #numpad id. I am using the jQuery.NumPad library https://github.com/kabachello/jQuery.NumPad. I know this is easy if the id is unique, but I want the id and class all the same.

```
<a href="#" id="numpad">
    <span class="amount"></span>
</a>
<a href="#" id="numpad">
    <span class="amount"></span>
</a>
<a href="#" id="numpad">
    <span class="amount"></span>
</a>
```

This one works, but the issue is the user input is displayed on all 3 'amount' class.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#numpad').numpad({
     target: $('bet-amt')
    });
</script>
```

I tried this one but i get console error "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing name after . operator"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#numpad').numpad({
     target: $(this).('bet-amt')
    });
</script>
```

Comment: "*but I want the id [...] all the same.*" Huh? This isn't valid HTML - IDs specifically "must  be unique in the whole document" ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)) in order to be compliant with the HTML specification. Why *exactly* do you want to do this? It'll only make it harder for yourself, and it seems at face value that this requirement is very very arbitrary.

Comment: Ok, if i change id to class, will it fix my issue?

Comment: It *looks like* you want to change `id=numpad` to `class='numpad'` then use `$('.numpad').numpad({ target: $('bet-amt', this) });`

Comment: However, the examples are far a few between and the "documentation" doesn't say you can (or can't) use `this` for `target:`  (https://a.kabachnik.info/jquery-numpad.html parameters tab)

Comment: I tried to replace id=numpad to class='numpad' then use  use $('.numpad').numpad({ target: $('bet-amt', this) }); but it won't work

Comment: Yes, that is my problem. I can't target the specific element

Comment: The html demo https://github.com/kabachello/jQuery.NumPad/blob/master/demos/bootstrap/index.html has several ways to target where you like to display the user input.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution to my problem. I replaced the id="numpad" to class="numpad". And changed my script to:

```
 $(function(){
               $('.numpad').each(function(){
                $(this).numpad({
                    target: $('.bet-amt', this)
                });
            });
        });
```

Thanks!